# How to read file from a particular directory in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, filereader, flutter-file

I am new to flutter. I wanted to read the files from a specific directory in file manager of the device and then use the data from those files in my app.
My files are in Internal storage->scan(a folder which i have created)->file1.txt,file2.csv.

Could you please help me out and let me know how to go forward with it?
The images are embedded in the hyperlink below.
[Directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z9By.png)

[File image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34MD2.png)

Comment: Use path provider for directory access and list files from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty straightforward documentation on this subject in the official Flutter docs here:

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Otherwise there are many other resources out there that can get you started.  A roadblock you might have is dart:io is not compatible for Flutter Web.  If Web is part of your target platforms, you'd have to look into an alternative library like Universal IO: https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io

Lastly, for future posts I'd recommend trying something first and asking more specific questions on here where you can provide code that you have at least tried first.  Then we can give you and other users more directed answers to the problems you are having.